# SwiftUI - Display nested Array in JSON response - try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions

Tags: json, foreach, swiftui

I have the following JSON response.

```
{
   "results":[
      {
         "TrimName":"Truck",
         "VIN":"GTJ3E18JF164623",
         "Price": 47600,
         "Odometer": 35511,
         "OdometerType": "Miles",
         "OptionCodeSpecs":{
            "C_SPECS":{
               "code":"C_SPECS",
               "name":"Specs",
               "options":[
                  {
                     "code":"SPECS_ACCELERATION",
                     "name":"5.2 sec",
                     "long_name":"5.2 seconds",
                     "description":"0-60 mph"
                  },
                  {
                     "code":"SPECS_TOP_SPEED",
                     "name":"140 mph",
                     "long_name":"140 miles per hour",
                     "description":"Top Speed"
                  },
                  {
                     "code":"SPECS_RANGE",
                     "name":"264 mi",
                     "long_name":"264 miles",
                     "description":"range (EPA)"
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   ],
   "total_matches_found":"53"
}
```

I built the Struct using app.quicktype.io.

```
// MARK: - InventoryModel
struct InventoryModel: Codable {
    let results: [Result]
    let totalMatchesFound: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case results
        case totalMatchesFound = "total_matches_found"
    }
}

// MARK: - Result
struct Result: Codable {
    let trimName, vin: String
    let price, odometer: Int
    let odometerType: String
    let optionCodeSpecs: OptionCodeSpecs

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case trimName = "TrimName"
        case vin = "VIN"
        case price = "Price"
        case odometer = "Odometer"
        case odometerType = "OdometerType"
        case optionCodeSpecs = "OptionCodeSpecs"
    }
}

// MARK: - OptionCodeSpecs
struct OptionCodeSpecs: Codable {
    let cSpecs: CSpecs

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case cSpecs = "C_SPECS"
    }
}

// MARK: - CSpecs
struct CSpecs: Codable {
    let code, name: String
    let options: [Option]
}

// MARK: - Option
struct Option: Codable {
    let code, name, longName, optionDescription: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case code, name
        case longName = "long_name"
        case optionDescription = "description"
    }
}
```

I am able to successfully retrieve the JSON response successfully.

```
@Published var getInventoryQuery: InventoryModel = InventoryModel(results: [], totalMatchesFound: "")
```

In my ContentView I am able to display the data at the Results object, but I am unable to get to the options array in the OptionCodeSpecs object without the following error:

The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions

Xcode Version 12.5.1 (12E507)

```
@ObservedObject var inv = GetInventory()
```

The following works great.  Code tripped out for clarity.

```
ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false){
                
                HStack(spacing: 10){
                    
                    ForEach(inv.getInventoryQuery.results, id: \.trimName) { inventory in
                        
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            
                            VStack(alignment: .center) {
                                
                                Text(inventory.trimName)
```

However, when I try and get to the options array, I get the following error:

```
The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions

HStack(alignment: .center){
                                    
                                    ForEach(inv.getInventoryQuery.results[inventory].optionCodeSpecs.cSpecs.options) { options in
                                    Text(options.longName)
                                        .font(.headline)
                                        .fontWeight(.light)
                                    
                                    Image(systemName: "battery.100")
                                        .renderingMode(.original)
                                    }
                                }
```

Comment: Try: `ForEach(inv.getInventoryQuery.results[inventory].optionCodeSpecs.cSpecs.options, id: \.code) { options in`

Comment: Thanks.  I can't believe I missed the ID:

Comment: When I change the ForEach to:  ForEach(inventory.optionCodeSpecs.cSpecs.options, id: \.code) Xcode still complains "The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions"

Comment: And have you tried to break it up into smaller parts as the compiler suggests?

Comment: @jnpdx - the problem turned out to be how I had my ForEach and Stacks.  I think Xcode was freaking out on how I was creating the view.